# How does niche optimization for an enum work in Rust?

Tags: rust, enums

Using `Option<bool>` as an example, I get that the sizes of `Option<bool>` and `bool` are both 1 byte, but I'm still not 100% about how the memory allocation of its variants occur.

Does it work like the following?

`Some(true)` to `00000001`

`Some(false)` to `00000000`

`None` something (changed from "anything" as per below comments) other than `00000001` or `00000000` (ex: `00000010`)

Comment: None is 2 (0b10) for me, but this is likely an implementation detail and not guaranteed. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c91332c8efed7f71f4a331c384bb04e.

Comment: What is guaranteed is that `None` will be a single value. The other 253 values are invalid.

Comment: "None anything other than 00000001 or 00000000 (ex: 00000010)" None *could* be anything other than 0x0 and 0x1 so you can't rely on it (because the values selected by niche optimisation are not deterministic, unless there's a single possible niche), but the value must be consistent, otherwise different `None` values would not be consistent. So "something other than 0x0 or 0x1" is probably closer to the truth.

Comment: @Masklinn Agree, and add some references.   

1. [Enum Sizes](https://google.github.io/comprehensive-rust/enums/sizes.html?highlight=Nich#enum-sizes)
2. [Layout of Rust enum types](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/enums.html#enum-layout-rules)

Comment: Note it is even not guaranteed that niche optimization will take place.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman according to [the unsafe code guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/enums.html#layout-of-a-data-carrying-enums-without-a-repr-annotation) it's at least guaranteed for "option-like enums" aka with two variants where one variant has a single field and the other one has no field.

Comment: @Masklinn Yeah but `bool` is not guaranteed to have a niche.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman it's specified as being either 0x0 or 0x1 (other values are UB) and [one byte](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html), so it's guaranteed to have 254 niches.

Comment: @Masklinn The fact that it is only 1 or 0 doesn't mean it is guaranteed the other values will be used for `Option`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman meh, it's been so [for 6 years](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/45225#issue-264795374) and it seems unlikely to break as [it's one of the specifically tested cases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e7409258db4a43f23dcc66e10061dee91c316055/tests/ui/print_type_sizes/niche-filling.stdout#L100-L103), so it would require a rather strong motivation to specifically be reverted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will print the byte values of all 3 possible values for `Option<bool>`:

```rs
fn main() {
    let a:[Option<bool>;3]=[Some(true), Some(false), None];
    
    for i in a {
        // Re-Interpret the bytes of the option as a number
        let j:u8 = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(i) };
        println!("{i:?} {j:?}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Some(true) 1
Some(false) 0
None 2
```

Seems like `None` is represented as 2.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=200add76cb64abff4c2401915873025e)

Note this isn't officially specified so it may change in future versions. Do not rely on this behavior.